# Binding WPF Properties such as IsEnabled to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, mvvm, binding

I'm looking for a way to compress a lot of superfluous Bindings in my code into a single dictionary.

In my ViewModel I have a dictionary:

```
 private Dictionary<string, bool> _myDict;
    public Dictionary<string, bool> MyDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return _myDict;
        }
        set
        {
            _myDict = value;
        }
    }
```

Pretty simple. On the front side I'd like to be able to bind the IsEnabled to a dictionary entry. For example, if I have the KVP `("FirstBorder", false)`, then I'd like this border to have IsEnabled set to false

```
<Border Width="30" Height="25" IsEnabled="{Binding MyDictionary[FirstBorder]}">
```

This code doesn't actually work - I'm looking for what I'd have to do to be able to be able specify a string Key in the Dictionary and have the property set based on its Value. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are absolutely the worst thing to bind against for a number of different reasons. Better to use a [KeyedCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) against a custom type (the `TItem` in the collection) that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). You get the benefits of using a key to access a value, and property change notification when the value changes.

And if you truly want to be badass, implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on your KeyedCollection implementation.  That'll make 'em jealous.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for what I'd have to do to be able to be able specify a string Key in the Dictionary and have the property set based on its Value. Is it even possible?

Yes, this should work:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Dictionary<string, bool> _myDict;
    public Dictionary<string, bool> MyDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return _myDict;
        }
        set
        {
            _myDict = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _myDict = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        _myDict.Add("FirstBorder", true);
        DataContext = this;
    }
}



<Button Content="Button" Width="30" Height="25" IsEnabled="{Binding MyDictionary[FirstBorder]}" />
```

Make sure that the object with your MyDictionary property is the DataContext of the element in the view that you are trying to enable/disable.

**Edit:** Note that the status of the element in the view will NOT be updated dynamically when you update the Boolean value in the dictionary dynamically at runtime since the Dictionary class doesn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raises change notifications.

If you want this you will either need to update the binding explicitly:

```
_myDict["FirstBorder"] = true;
var be = button.GetBindingExpression(Button.IsEnabledProperty);
if (be != null)
  be.UpdateTarget();
```

...or bind to a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged correctly.

Comment: Does it not need an UpdateProperty somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you intending the update the value in the dictionary from the UI or what?

Comment: The value is updated throughout the program as appropriate. Using the code as shown doesn't ever actually update the IsEnabled flag.

Comment: `DataContext = this;` vomit

Comment: Oh, the status of the element in the view will NOT be updated dynamically when you update the Boolean value in the dictionary dynamically at runtime since the Dictionary class doesn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raises change notifications. Please refer to my edited answer for more information.